# How I can clone a magento2 website settings (catalog, and stores) if I have the code in a git repo?

Tags: magento2, installation

I have my Magento website in a git repo. For local development, I try to replicate the production environment into my own setup with a different domain.

I managed to have basic php running, but I want to clone the store settings and the catalog from one Magento setup to my local one.

So far, in my local setup, I have managed to run the following:

```
git clone ^repo^ ./repo_folder
cd ./repo_folder
php bin/magento setup:install
```

I have setup my local db with an admin user. If I get a database dump and a server's env.php, am I able to reproduce the remote environment on my own?

I want to have the remote Magento setup (from a given codebase) as my own but with a change domain from mymagentostore.example.com -> mymagentostore.local

Is there a tool that runs upon GNU/Linux and can clone the necessary settings into my local environment from a given git repo and admin?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but I would just pull over all files so that you're not leaving behind all of the catalog's media assets. Those typically aren't tracked in the repo. You can reattach your .git to the local codebase after the fact.

Personally I would dump a copy of the database in the web root of your remote instance and then rsync everything over to your local dev environment. Import the database and then adjust the `app/etc/env.php` and the base_url(s) and cookie settings in the `core_config_data` table as needed. Ensure your file permissions and owners are correct within magento's recommended specs, clear the cache, reindex, and you should be good to go.